# Change a single value from an array of objects after iterating in javaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code:

```
let user = [
    {id: 1, name: "Chris", active: "true"},
    {id: 2, name: "James", active: "true"},
    {id: 3, name: "Jeremy", active: "true"},
];

handleClick = () => {
    for(let i in user) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(user, i)) {
                user[i].active = false;
         }
    }
};
```

Hi.

I've been looking over many topics but i don't find any answers to my question.

As you can see on a click (handleClick) I want to modify the status of active to "true" to "false" and vice versa. But I want that this happen only on the user that I click, not all of the them. Each user has his own button.

I start to think that maybe I should use the id somehow.

Comment: Is this from a **ReactJS** app ? How is the `handleClick` function called ?

Comment: Yes it is sir :) But i don't want to put the whole thing. I prefer to start from JS and then adapt.

Comment: I've asked that because it matters how the elements in the `user` array are associated with the DOM elements.

Comment: Ok i see ! Let me make some order in my code and drop what is needed :)

Comment: Please post a working example using a code snippet or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
let user = [
    {id: 1, name: "Chris", active: "true"},
    {id: 2, name: "James", active: "true"},
    {id: 3, name: "Jeremy", active: "true"},
];

handleClick = id => {
    user.forEach( obj => {
      if(obj.id === id) 
     obj.active = !obj.active;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ES6` to handle this function also if you trying to use `boolean` you should write `true` or `false` without  `quotation` or `double-quotation`

```js
let user = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Chris",
    active: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "James",
    active: true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Jeremy",
    active: true
  },
];

function handleClick(id) { // handleClick = (id) => {
  const result = user.map(obj =>
    obj.id === id ? { ...obj,
      active: !obj.active
    } : obj
  )
  console.log(result)
}
```

```html
<div onclick="handleClick(1)">Click</div>

<!-- React version -> <div onClick="this.handleClick(id)">Click</div> -->
```

Comment: @JeremyBertin Glad to help, please select the best answer that solved your problem as accepted answer or `+1` *up vote!* (It's your choice!)

Answer (score 0):

I saw you used a [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) so what you are looking for is something like this:

```js
handleClick = id => {
  let arr = this.state.users.map(user => {
    let u = { ...user };

    if(u.id === id) {
      u.active = !u.active;
    }

    return u;
  });

  this.setState({ users: arr });
}
```

Check out this demo:

```js
let users = [
  {id: 1, name: "Chris", active: true}, 
  {id: 2, name: "James", active: false}, 
  {id: 3, name: "Jeremy", active: true}
];

class Demo extends React.Component {
    state = { users };
    
    colorize = active => active ? 'green' : 'red';
    
    handleClick = id => {
      let arr = this.state.users.map(user => {
        let u = { ...user };
        
        if(u.id === id) {
          u.active = !u.active;
        }
        
        return u;
      })
      
      this.setState({ users: arr });
    }
    
    render (){
        return (
         <div>
           {this.state.users.map(user => (
            <div key={user.id} className="row">
              <p className="user">{user.name}</p>
              <p className={`status ${this.colorize(user.active)}`}>
                {user.active.toString()}
              </p>
              <button 
                onClick={() => this.handleClick(user.id)}>
                Change status
              </button>
            </div>
           ))}
         </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.user {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.user::after {
  content: ":";
}

.status {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

button {
  margin: 15px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.red { 
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Problem have been solved already but it's always nice to have a different approach.

Answer (score -1):

Pass in the ID of the user in the function then add a if statement

```
(id) =>{ user.forEach( obj =>{
 If(obj.id === id) 
obj.active = !obj.active;
})}
```

Comment: Damn. This looks great ! Gone try this right away :)

Comment: @JeremyBertin glad I could help!